# Gradle Shadow plugin relocate an SPI service while preserving the service file name in META-INF/services

Tags: gradle, jar, shadow

I wonder how can I package a JAR with Gradle Shadow plugin where one would relocate a third-party Service Provider (SPI) while preserving the service file name in META-INF/services (just the name, the content should be relocated)?

Example of what I want to achieve:

**INPUT:**

```
/java
  /some/Service.class                
/resources
  /META-INF/services/some.Service
```

**OUTPUT** (following shadow relocate):

```
/java
        
   /relocated/Service.class 
/resources
   /META-INF/services/some.Service    <<< The filename intact while the content relocated
```

I have tried various exclude strategies with no success. My current theory would be that I would need to add an additional JAR step that would unpack the ShadowJar, rename the file and re-package the Jar.